# RegEx to find a list of words that are not in the input

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm using RegEx to try and find a list of phrases that are not in the input.

Some time ago, I asked a similar question and got the answer I needed using the first example below which correctly captures  all words not in the pattern. In this case it captures 'newlabel'.

What I now need is something similar, but instead of capturing 'newlabel' I need it to return any phrase in the pattern that isn't in the input at the start of a line.

I'm doing this is C#.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
(^|\r\n).*?:(?<!(^|\r\n)(?:label1|label2|label3|some label):)

Input: 
label1: value 
label2: value
label3: value
newlabel: value
```

This correctly gets 'newlabel'.

What I now need is something similar, but instead of getting 'newlabel' I need it to return 'some label', or any phrase in the pattern that isn't in the input at the start of a line.

```
(^|\r\n).*?:(?<!(^|\r\n)(?:label1|label2|label3|some label):)

Input: 
label1 new value
label2 a value
label3 anything
newlabel something
```

In the end the phrase 'some label' should the only thing captured

Comment: `I'm doing this is C#.` but you tagged vb.net

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?!(?:label[123]|newlabel)\b).*$`  [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!%28%3f%3alabel%5b123%5d%7cnewlabel%29%5cb%29.*%24&i=label1+new+value%0d%0alabel2+a+value%0d%0alabel3+anything%0d%0anewlabel+something%0d%0asome+label&o=m)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that maybe you might be trying to design an expression that'd somewhat look like:

```
^(?!(^\b(?:label1|label2|label3|newlabel)\b))([^:]*?)\s*:\s*([^\r\n]*)$
```

maybe, not sure though.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aHm4zn/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/aHm4zn/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Emma , but this isn't quite what I needed. I need the value 'some label' from the pattern to be captured, not the text in the input.
I need it to tell me that one of the words in the pattern is not in the input.
Hope this makes sense

My project is to make sure users have sent in the input with all the correct fields added. This regex has to tell me if there is a field missing in the users input.

Comment: Hi @Emma, although I wasn't able to use your code line for it's original purpose, I was able to use it to replace a rather ugly line. So great. Thanks :)